# Omniauth : retrieve the name of the strategy that has failed in /auth/failure callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

what is the best way to retrieve the name of the strategy that has just failed in my failure callback action ?

Do I need to setup a custom failure end point just to retrieve the name of the strategy (I hope not :)) ?

Thanks :).

Comment: hum i've looked at the source code of omniauth for half an hour and unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to do this without implementing a custom failure end point. :(

Comment: what do you want to do with the failed strategy name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay !

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/commit/13c36914c290dae8426359e494262ddab29d49a5